# Get Error - The method getText must be called from the UI thread, currently inferred thread is worker

Tags: java, android, multithreading

In the line below it gives me the error saying:

> The method getText must be called from the UI thread, currently inferred thread is worker”.

How do I resolve that error ?

```
// Get the text from EditText
String wordsToTranslate = **translateEditText.getText()**.toString();
```

The bold portion is where it tells me there is an error. Any Idea on how to solve this?

[Screen shot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuAO9.jpg)

Comment: You can not do UI related operation in "doInBackgound" method

Comment: You can work with UI (EditText is a part of UI) only from UI thread. `doInBackground` is supposed to be called in background thread. That is the problem. Get text outside `doInBackground`, for example in `onPreExecute`

Comment: Thanks for the fast response guys. I just had to remove that line of code and put it before the override ( meaning outside the doInBackground ) and it fixed the problem. Thanks for all the help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

String wordsToTranslate = translateEditText.getText().toString();

new Translate().execute(wordsToTranslate);

```
class Translate extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            String wordsToTranslate = args[0];


            //do your work

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every app has its own special thread that runs UI objects and you can only access UI objects from that thread.

You should look into the android developer site about communicating with the UI thread:

https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html